# What kind of sealant to use by foundation?

Tags: basement, foundation, waterproofing, sealing, driveway

I have a small gap between my patio cement and foundation wall. I'd like to seal it to prevent water from going straight down. What is the best type of sealer to use? Here is a picture of the area I'd like to seal. [image: foundation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sikaflex or similar is the standard, however that gap seems pretty thin.  Is it less than 1/4"?  You can get this in a self leveling format or not.  My best guess would be to not have the self leveling due to not being able to insert a backer rod to prevent the caulking from dripping too deep into the gap.

Comment: Yes it's less than a 1/4". Pretty small gap. I almost wonder if a caulk of some kind would work...

Comment: Yes - sikaflex or similar comes in a caulk format.  Don't use the thinner self leveling specific version.  Perhaps the crack filler would do:http://t.homedepot.com/p/Sikaflex-10-fl-oz-Crack-Sealant-427706/203249445